# Cowboy Listeners

Tags: erlang, cowboy, ranch

Trying to find detailed information about listeners and using more than one listener for application. 
So I am wondering what may happen if I continue to use about 15 listeners with different ports on production.

Seems like everything is good for now excepts cpu latency (about 7\8 on 10core processor)

The settings are (for each listener):

```
"acceptor_pool": 200,
"connects_opts": {"max_connections": 130000, "max_keepalive": 130000}
```

Could you please show me the right direction with detailed information or there is no deal with it and I can use listeners as more as I want

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you should see no issues with several listeners, as they are independent, but are so many acceptors really needed? We have 10 acceptors per node and we are able to serve ~350req/s easily.

Regarding the 'detailed information', I like this [Cloudflare post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-sad-state-of-linux-socket-balancing/) a lot (it's not erlang-specific).

Comment: thx for you reply and link. I will take a look. regarding acceptor pool, we now having 2000rps average but sometimes we are facing about 3\4k requests per second